# Set filename as variable in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, filenames

Am new to this so hope someone can assist a novice. Cannot locate the answer so far. Essentially I am trying to create a watch folder which picks up new .MXF files, runs a specific command line application and renames the new file with the original filename plus _new.

```
@echo off 
:loop 
if exist "C:\Input\*.mxf" (
for %%a in ("C:\Input\*.mxf") do (
C:\BMX\bmxtranswrap -o C:\Output\NEW.mxf -t as11op1a -y 09:59:50:00 --afd 10 --pass-anc all -anc-max 2048 "%%a" 
ping -n 5 localhost >nul
del "%%a" 
) 
) 
ping -n 5 localhost >nul 
goto :loop
```

I originally tried using `%~n1` command to pass through the name which works in a CMD script I have.

```
C:\BMX\bmxtranswrap -o C:\Output\%~n1_NEW.mxf -t as11op1a -y 09:59:50:00 --afd 10 --pass-anc all -anc-max 2048 "%%a"
```

This doesn't work however. If there is a command I am missing to pass through the source filename then please let me know. 
Many thanks.

Comment: run it with `@echo ON` to see what happens. Analyze the command repetition and note any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the filename without the extension in order to use it as a variable in the new name.
To get the filename you can use:

```
%%~ni
```

This should work:

```
@echo off 
if exist "C:\Input\*.mxf" (
FOR %%i IN ("c:\Input\*.mxf") DO (
REM ECHO %%~ni - This is the filename without the extensoion for the new file
C:\BMX\bmxtranswrap -o C:\Output\%%~ni_new.mxf -t as11op1a -y 09:59:50:00 --afd 10 --pass-anc all -anc-max 2048 %%i 
ping -n 5 localhost >nul
del %%i
) 
)
```

---

**NOTE:**
I've tested the above code without the `bmxtranswrap` line and the new filenames were displayed as expected: `test_new.mxf` and `test2_new.mxf`

Comment: Hi, Thanks! So %%i is for any new input in the folder and %%~ni is a new filename based off that new input (%%i)? Have I got that correct?